# Can a CGImage be added to the contents property of a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a custom view with a layerClass override like:

```
+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}
```

I want to be able to add a CGImage to the contents property like so:

```
- (void) animateView
{
    UIImage *layerImage = ...;
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;
    layer.contents = layerImage.CGImage;

    //....Do other fun animations here
}
```

Are there other properties I need to set, or other ways to get the shape layer to render the contents of the image for animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume not: `CAShapeLayer` is pretty much just used to render a vector path. Have you tried creating a generic layer, assigning your image as its contents, and adding it as a sublayer of your shape layer?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either. I am going with a different approach to the problem, but I figured this would be much easier...i guess not.

Comment: I know you can assign CGImageRef's to the `contents` property of a CALayer. Perhaps the image is in an unsupported format?