# Is it possible to add a background Image to a CAShape? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cashapelayer

I am trying to distort an image in an arbitrary way, following for example a bezier shape. I have used CAShapeLayer to create the shape, but then it seems that setting its contents to an Image does not work. How can I have the image distorted following that shape? Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible. I would suggest filing a radar [(http://bugreport.apple.com)](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you think this should be supported.

See also: [Can a CGImage be added to the contents property of a CAShapeLayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167493/can-a-cgimage-be-added-to-the-contents-property-of-a-cashapelayer)

Comment: Hi casademora, Thanks for your answer. What is the best way then to distort an image in a shape that follows for example a Bezier Path? Do I have to move to openGL ES and textures?

Comment: I stopped my investigation when I found that option wasn't supported. My guess is that using OpenGL will give you more options...you could create a shape, and map your image as a texture, but that is as much as I know about openGL... :(

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible to do so, but i succeeded in doing so by putting a CALayer on top a CAShapeLayer.
this is my code:

```
CALayer *image =[CALayer layer];
image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75);
image.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"number-1"].CGImage;    
 [self.layer addSublayer:image];



UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)];
blueCircleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
blueCircleLayer.path = circle.CGPath;
blueCircleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
blueCircleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
blueCircleLayer.shadowColor =[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
blueCircleLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
blueCircleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
blueCircleLayer.lineWidth = 7.0;

[self.layer addSublayer:blueCircleLayer];
```

Comment: On the right track, extend from this and set the mask of `image` to `blueCircleLayer`.