# How to transform a circle into a line in swift?

Tags: swift, graphics, transform

So i have a circe with a certain pattern. I want to make transform this circle into a line. Any ideas how i could accomplish this?

I did have a look at making a UIBezierPath over the circle for then to transform this into a line without any help. I've also seen a link doing this in opencv ([fast Cartesian to Polar to Cartesian in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924135/fast-cartesian-to-polar-to-cartesian-in-python)) but do prefer to do this in native swift.

[image]

Comment: Did you try something? Any code?

Comment: Ive looked at creating a UIBezierPath to cover the circle and then transforming this into a line but without luck.

Comment: Maybe add you best try to the question and somebody can help

Comment: Do you know the diameter or the radius? If you find one of this you can find the perimeter and create a UIView of 1px height (or the thickness you want for your line) and "Perimeter" width.

For example (if radius = 3):
Perimeter = 2*Pi*3 = 18.85.

Comment: I do know the radius. Once i've created the view, should i just set the image of the view to be the circle image? It will then transform the circle image into a line?

Comment: You can try that. If it doesn't work you can hide the circle one and create the line afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the nature of the transition, the easiest way is to do `CABasicAnimation`, animating the `path` of a `CAShapeLayer` from one path to another. And to achieve a patterned path with `CAShapeLayer` is actually to have two overlapping `CAShapeLayer` objects, one with a dash pattern on top of one without.

```
let fromPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI) * 2.0, clockwise: true)
let toPath = UIBezierPath()
toPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2.0 - CGFloat(M_PI) * 100.0, y:view.center.y))
toPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2.0 + CGFloat(M_PI) * 100.0, y: view.center.y))

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = fromPath.CGPath
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer2.path = fromPath.CGPath
shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 5
shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
shapeLayer2.lineDashPattern = [100,50]

view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
```

And

```
shapeLayer.path = toPath.CGPath
shapeLayer2.path = toPath.CGPath

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(5)

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation.fromValue = fromPath.CGPath
animation.toValue = toPath.CGPath
shapeLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)

let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation2.fromValue = fromPath.CGPath
animation2.toValue = toPath.CGPath
shapeLayer2.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)

CATransaction.commit()
```

Yielding:

[image]

If you want more control over the nature of the transition, then you have to resort to more manual techniques, e.g. a `CADisplayLink` in which you manually adjust the path. But that's more complicated.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for such a informative and good answer! The only problem is was my formulation of the problem. The circle does not have a pre decided pattern, but is an Image, any future advice?

Comment: It is a non-trivial exercise to convert a random bitmap image into a shape and then proceed  to that transform

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but is it? I could make a color with pattern image: 
var color = UIColor(patternImage: image!) and set the strokeColor. But it did not work as hoped. 

I cant add an image to a CAShapeLayer and a CALayer does not have  a path property. 

All i found was: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578801/is-it-possible-to-add-a-background-image-to-a-cashape-iphone

Comment: @Rob great answer! +1 for sharing your experience.

Comment: @LarsErik - Yes, patternImage doesn't work as expected here, which is why I did what I did. And, no, you can just add image and expect it to transform like a `UIBezierPath`/`CGPath` can. They're completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, The animation is not perfect, but you will be able to convert an image to a line this way. I have to say that Rob's solution above is far more superior and if I were give a choice, i would do it his way.

The below code is very self-explanatory, but if in case of any doubt, feel free to ask.

To make the animation happen, tap the yellow button.

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var imageView : UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 120
        image.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        image.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        return image
    }()

    var animatorButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        button.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        return button
    }()

    var constraintHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(animatorButton)

        view.addConstraint(view.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.centerXAnchor))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[imageView(240)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView]))

        self.constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-100-[imageView(240)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView])
        view.addConstraints(constraintHeight)


        view.addConstraint(animatorButton.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-450-[Button(40)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["Button": animatorButton]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[Button]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["Button": animatorButton]))


        animatorButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.animateImageToLine), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func animateImageToLine() {

        view.removeConstraints(constraintHeight)
        constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-100-[imageView(3)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView])
        view.addConstraints(constraintHeight)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
               self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


            }, completion: { success in
                self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        })

    }
    }
```